# Game development : Guidance require for texture detail and number of texture allow per model

Tags: modeling, texturing

A little background, I am a junior game artist that used to do low poly and stylize asset. But recently, I am being task to to create model with lot of intricate detail that require to be bake into normal.

Due to my inexperience, I am unable to fit all the UV within 1 texture while providing the suitable UV island size that doesn't end up making the baked Normal to be blurry or artifact free.

For model with many detail require to be bake. How would 1 usually fit everything in one texture without sacrificing the quality of the normal and the texture density ?

Note: While it will not have a extreme close up, player are allow to zoom in close to their character. Hence, I am not really able to hide it through distant....

Comment: I think you'd be better asking that question on https://blenderartists.org/ as answers here are likely to be opinion-based and therefore off-topic for this site.

Comment: ok noted, thank you